# /etc/hosts file of a docker container gets overwritten

Tags: networking, docker

I create a docker container from a centOS 6.5 image. I make some changes to the /etc/hosts file.
I then commit the container, and start the new image in a new container, and the /etc/hosts file gets overwritten. Is there a way of keeping the /etc/hosts file as it is?

Answer (score 9):

No.  See discussion [here](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/2267).

Docker does different things with `/etc/hosts` depending on what option you give to `--net`.  In the default (bridged) mode, it writes an entry for the hostname and IP address of the container itself.  There is no option where it leaves `/etc/hosts` as in the source image.

Your options include:

- have your container modify `/etc/hosts` at startup, before running the real program
- add entries to `/etc/hosts` when you run the container with the `--add-host` option.

Comment: I can modify what the container does at startup by putting the commands in ~/.bash_profile ?

Comment: You can simply pick a different command, e.g. `ENTRYPOINT my_wrapper_script`, and that does the config and runs whatever used to be your `ENTRYPOINT`.  But yes, putting stuff in `.profile` or similar will work, so long as the `ENTRYPOINT` is a shell script.